# How to access volume mount with python script?

Tags: python, kubernetes, yaml

I have been trying to use something along these lines to access a file in a volume mount:

```
with open('./log/file.json', 'w+') as f:
    f.write(json.dumps(output, sort_keys=True, indent=4))
```

but it is not working. Are there any ideas? In my deployment file, I have this:

```
volumeMounts:
- mountPath: /logs
  name: wag-log
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've defined a `volumeMount` with the `mountPath` set to `/logs`, which would mount a volume into the `/logs` directory. In your Python code you're writing at the path `./log/file.json`, which is not in `/logs`.

Try to write a log to the directory you mounted, for example:

```py
with open('/logs/file.json', 'w+') as f:
    f.write(json.dumps(output, sort_keys=True, indent=4))
```